# include environment specific file in playframework

Tags: java-8, playframework-2.2

Is it possible to achieve this in an `application.conf` file?

```
env = ${?ENV}".auth.conf" 
include env
```

The 'include' statement does not accept env. As far as I know, I can only pass a string to `include`, like:

```
include "dev.auth.conf"
```

Is there a way to specify a `variable` to the `'include'` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

From the [HOCON spec](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/v1.3.0/HOCON.md#include-syntax)

> Value concatenation is NOT performed on the "argument" to include or url() etc. The argument must be a single quoted string. No substitutions are allowed, and the argument may not be an unquoted string or any other kind of value.

The hypothetical feature is complicated.

```
a = ${b}
b = 1
```

resolves to `a = 1`. In that pattern,

```
include ${b}.conf
b = 1
```

should include `1.conf`.

But what if `b = 1` is defined in another include? Is

```
include filehavingb.conf
include ${b}.conf
```

different than

```
include ${b}.conf
include filehavingb.conf
```

And other complications.

Anyway, this is discussed at https://github.com/typesafehub/config/issues/122

The easiest way to achieve a similar result currently is using `-Dconfig.file`

Comment: Thanks Paul. Just saw your answer.